# LINQ fails to create database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

The following code example fails randomly on some PC's. On other PC's the problem cannot be reproduced. All PC's are running .NET 3.5 SP1 on Vista SP1.

```
string connection = @"Data Source=PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDatabase ;User Id=sa;Password=ThePassword;";

TestDatabase db = new TestDatabase (connection);

if (!db.DatabaseExists())
{
    db.CreateDatabase();
}
```

`DatabaseExists()` returns `false` but `CreateDatabase()` throws this Exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Database 'TestDatabase ' already
>   exists. Choose a different database
>   name.

The documentation states that `DatabaseExists()` returns true if the database exists and can be opened.

What could cause the database not to be available?

**EDIT:** The database server is SQL Server Express 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection issues are caused by the AUTO_CLOSE property was set to true. This is default for all SQL Server Express 2008 databases.

Setting this feature to off solved the issue:

```
ALTER DATABASE [database] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF
```

Because AUTO_CLOSE stops the database after 30 seconds idle time, this also solved other unexplained database-related errors in the application.

[More info on AUTO_CLOSE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/02/22/sql-express-behaviors-idle-time-resources-usage-auto-close-and-user-instances.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It could be a rights issue, i.e. the database exists but you don't have permission to open it. That would return a `false` and also the exception you provided.

Comment: The strange thing is that the problem comes and goes on some machines. I.e. one moment it fails the next its succeeds.

Comment: Is that on successive executions of your code, without doing anything (and I mean anything) in between? If so then it's very odd indeed.

Comment: I do during startup of an application. If i get the error - i just restart the application and i usually works right away.

Comment: Very odd, it's effectively looking as though `DatabaseExists` is nondeterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Just created a simple Windows Application with the following code...

```
       string connection = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDatabase;Integrated Security=True";

        LinqToSQLDataContext dc = new LinqToSQLDataContext(connection);

        if (!dc.DatabaseExists())
        {
            dc.CreateDatabase();
        }
```

Ensure that there was no database with the name TestDatabase. As the code works as expected. The only difference in my case is that I am use Integrated Security. Of course, this is not the complete code, and I would get an error as expected at dc.CreateDatabase as follows...

[image]

Hence, I can confirm that the code is good. It looks like you don't have enough perms on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a multi-user race condition?

```
User1: test database existance (false)
User2: test database existance (false)
User1: create database
User2: create database (exception!)
```

Comment: It's a good theory, but the database already exists, when the app starts.